# How i can filter dataGrid on the basis of Column header in wpf?

Tags: wpf, datagridview, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datagridviewcolumn

Here is the code I'm just using Entity framework and loading value in dataGridview from database(Customer table).Now i want to filter datagrid on the basis of textbox value and again show only those values in dataGrid which are filter.

```
 DataContext obj = new DataContext();
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MailingListDataGrid.ItemsSource = obj.Customers.ToList();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: As a note, your DataContext class should be called ViewModel or MainViewModel or the like. You should assign an instance of that class to the DataContext property of the Window, like `DataContext = new ViewModel()`, and bind the ItemsSource in XAML like `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />`.

Comment: @Clemens ok let me try I inform you shortly.thanks